# Compile error after update Android Studio to 4.2

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Today, after update Android studio to version 4.2, i often get this errors, when i'm compiling my project:

> Execution failed for task ':app:compileLocalmfcDebugKotlin'.
>
> > java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java": CreateProcess error=206,
> > ��� ����� ��� ��� ���������� ����� ������� ������� �����

```
CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long at.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think after upgrading to Androi's Studio 4.2, you can do the following:

1. File -> Invalidate caches/Restart
2. If you are using Kotlin 1.5, you need to check whether the version of the Kotlin plugin is 1.5
3. For possible reasons of Gradle, you can delete the corresponding directory of Android Studio Gradle, and then recompile.
4. It may be the reason of your code itself, please check